# Python 3 - Scapy sniff filter options

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, scapy

I am using Scapy sniff function to track incoming traffic on local interface. I would like to isolate and print just specific packets. In order to do so, I have to match values in specific fields of TCP/UDP/IP headers. Is there detailed document that explains usage of Scapy sniff filters? How can I set filter to refer to some packet filed value?

For example, I would need filter that shows just and only SYN+ACK packets. For some reason this is not working as expected:

```
sniff(iface="Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM",
      filter="ip src x.x.x.x and tcp-syn !=0 and tcp-rst !=1",
      prn=lambda x: x.summary)
```

Answer (score 1):

The filter is written in standard BPF syntax, as documented here https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/pcap-filter.html

For your use case (only SYN-ACK packets), I think it would be something like this:

```
filter = "host x.x.x.x and (tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-ack)) == (tcp-syn|tcp-ack)"

sniff(iface="Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM",
      filter=filter, prn=lambda x: x.summary)
```